# Windows 7 64-bit on a late 2007 Mac Pro

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit, boot-camp

Is it possible to install Windows 7 64-bit on a late 2007 Mac Pro using Boot Camp?

If not, what about Windows Vista 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it's a MacPro2,1 (check using System Profiler.app) with an Intel Xeon 5300 series CPU. If so, that architecture is 64-bit and you should have no problem installing Windows 7 64-bit. Since it's likely not officially supported for Boot Camp x64 by Apple, you'll need to [manually install the 64-bit drivers](http://www.techulous.com/hardware/how-to-apple-boot-camp-64-bit-for-windows-7-on-unsupported-macs.html). Those instructions are recent and relevant for Boot Camp 3.0. It works well on my MacBook (Late 2008).

Comment: I tried this on a late 2007 MacBook Pro and it worked!

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac has a 64 bit processor (that is, a core duo or other dual core processor) and you are running snow leopard with bootcamp 3.0, I believe so.  I know it apparently works on a macBOOK pro, so I can't see why it wouldn't on a mac pro.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=704123